# Mathematics Teacher's Page?

Tags: discussion

I'm currently working in Mathematics Education Research and in my work, I've found that there is a serious deficiency in ways in which pre and current Mathematics Teachers are able to get support with their Mathematics.

In my viewpoint, I feel there would be great benefit to creating a separate Math Stack Exchange specifically devoted to Teachers seeking assistance with Mathematics. For instance, different methods, software, technology, etc etc.

And it must be a shame free environment. Teachers need to feel comfortable in asking questions.

The better job we can do as a community to support Mathematics teachers, the better the education and the better the student!

Comment: Do you mean [matheducators.se]?

Answer (score 15):

(I'm rewriting Asaf Karagila's comment as an answer so that this question is not left unanswered.)

You'd probably be interested in [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tour).